# Google Play Services Battery Drain

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms, battery

I have sony xperia l running Android kitkat4.4.4 AKOP rom 
I want to ask that my phones google play services draines my battery 60% to 80% 
I tried all kind of fix but nothing sloved my problem

Thanks

Comment: its displayed in settings >> battery

Comment: How ???
I didnt understand.